# Error in Atlassian SDK

Tags: maven, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am currently trying to get started with the Atlassian SDK and I've installed it as it is described in the Atlassian SDK Documentation. But when I'm running a SDK-command, it doesn't work. For example, when I run the command

```
atlas-run-standalone --product jira
```

it fails with the following output:

```
Executing: "C:\Users\XXX\Programme\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\mvn" com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-am
ps-plugin:4.2.20:run-standalone -gs C:\Users\XXX\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven/conf/settings.xm
l -Dproduct=jira
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-amps-plugin:4.2.20:run-standalone (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Google Analytics Tracking is enabled to collect AMPS usage statistics.
[INFO] Although no personal information is sent, you may disable tracking by adding <allowGoogleTracking>false
</allowGoogleTracking> to the amps plugin configuration in your pom.xml
[INFO] Sending event to Google Analytics: AMPS:jira - Run Standalone
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.861s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 24 09:32:47 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:4.2.20:run-standalone (
default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:ma
ven-amps-plugin:4.2.20:run-standalone failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing
com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:4.2.20:run-standalone: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: o
rg.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession.getRepositorySession()Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystemSe
ssion;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:4.2.20
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/maven/plugins/maven-amps-plugin/4
.2.20/maven-amps-plugin-4.2.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/core/atlassian-core/4.0/atlassian
-core-4.0.jar
# more [ERROR] urls[x] = ...
[ERROR] urls[130] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/org/twdata/maven/mojo-executor/1.5.1/mojo-exe
cutor-1.5.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following arti
cles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Some further information to my machine:

- Windows 7 Professional, x64
- javac 1.7.0_45
- JAVA_HOME is set, %JAVA_HOME%/bin has been added to PATH

And the information responded by the atlas-version command:

```
ATLAS Version:    4.2.20
ATLAS Home:       C:\Users\XXX\atlassian-plugin-sdk
ATLAS Scripts:    C:\Users\XXX\atlassian-plugin-sdk\bin
ATLAS Maven Home: C:\Users\XXX\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven
--------
Executing: "C:\Users\XXX\Programme\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\mvn" --versi
n-plugin-sdk\apache-maven/conf/settings.xml
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-1
Maven home: C:\Users\XXX\Programme\apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set `ATLAS_MVN` to use your own installation of Maven? The Atlassian SDK doesn't support Maven 3.1+ in the 4.x releases due to an incompatible change in Maven itself ([MNG-5354](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5354)).

There is a fix ([AMPS-1029](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/AMPS-1029)); until upgrading, use Maven 3.0 or the `mvn` that's bundled with AMPS.

AMPS 5.0 has now been released ([AMPS SDK 5.0.0 Release Notes](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/AMPS+SDK+5.0.0+Release+Notes)) with that fix included, and support for Maven 3.1.

Comment: I have indeed set `ATLAS_MVN` to Maven 3.1.1. But even when I use an older Version (e.g. 3.0) it doesn't work either.

Comment: Log is empty. But it was my mistake 3.0.5 didn't "work" because `M2_HOME` was still set to the Maven 3.1.1 directory. `atlas-run-standalone` as well as `atlas-create-jira-plugin` run as expected. Thanks for helping me.